# how log4j is self initialized

Tags: java, web, log4j, initialization

When we add `log4j` library in our *web-app* and put the `log4j.properties` file in classpath, then log4j is automatically initialized with the configuration written in the properties file. Right ?

Then my question is without writing anything in **web.xml** regarding log4j initialization how is log4j initialized automatically means how does it start to search the configuration file. Which class of log4j library does this ?

I have seen this type of behavior with some other libraries also. Can anyone please explain me  what happens in background ?

**Thanks**

Comment: Erm, it has a couple default places it looks. Nothing magical.

Comment: It's all a bunch of static initializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure();` function.

If you go through the configure function call, then in `LogManager` class, you will find `DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_FILE` static String variable which is set to `log4j.properties`. And in same class, in static method `url = Loader.getResource(DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_FILE);` line execute which initialize the resource with defined file path.

You can see more function calls in that static block which will guide through how it is instantiated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A static initializer declared in a class is executed when the class is initialized. So how is the BasicConfigurator.configure() called ?

Comment: @mukund for that, follow Logger.getLogger(...) method which you called to instantiate Logger object. In that method, you will find one call to LogMangager class.